# Efficiency of concurrent std::vector writes

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, vector, thread-safety

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Thread_safety, it is safe to write to different elements of one `std::vector`, from different threads.

But if the `value_type` is smaller than the word size of the CPU (or the [hardware destructive interference size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size)), like (`std::vector<char>`), does this mean that access to elements is less efficient than it could be without the requirement for thread safety?

For example, does the read/write access imply memory fence/atomic instructions?

Comment: It's the programmer's responsibility to guarantee there will be no concurrent writes to the same element. The standard doesn't mandate anything to help there (eg. no atomicity guarantees). If the programmer fulfills her responsibility, only then is it safe. If she doesn't, it's not safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is safe, standard requires it to be safe. However, it might be inefficient due to what is called 'false sharing'.

False sharing happens when to individual threads update adjacent memory, which belongs to the same cache line. If those threads happen to be executed on two different cores, they end up invalidating the cache line on both CPUs and trigger expensive cache updates.

Code writer should make reasonable efforts to make the false sharing less likely by trying to assign close indexes to the same thread.

And to answer question I have just seen in the original post - no, there will be no compiler-generated fences on such writes.

Comment: False sharing does cause inefficiency, but is that caused by the thread safety requirement of containers?

Comment: @user2079303, not sure if I understand the question. Standard requires parallel writes to two different elements of the vector to be thread safe, but it doesn't know anything about CPU caches.

Comment: My point is that the question is, "does the thread safety requirement make element access less efficient?". False sharing does make element access less efficient (in cases where it applies), but if that is not caused by the thread safety requirement, then that doesn't really answer the question, does it?

Comment: @user2079303, well, there is no direct connection, but I thought it is an important point to make.

Answer (score 0):

A conforming implementation of C++ must be able to write to a value of `char` without "inventing writes". In other words, `char` must be at least as big as the machine requires for isolated writes.

(It may still be *inefficient* to write to adjacent memory locations from multiple threads due to interference in the hierarchical memory, but it wouldn't be *incorrect*.)

Comment: The standard requires that `sizeof(char) == 1`

Comment: But when working on elements from a `std::vector` instead of local variables, it will not keep parts of the vector in CPU cache, and instead treat every read/write like an `std::atomic<char>` with `memory_order_seq_cst`?

Comment: @tmlen: That is irrelevant. Even if you have `char x[2]`, you can modify `x[0]` and `x[1]` in separate threads and that does not constitute a data race. They are different memory locations, and this is required to work. Similarly, elements of a vector are at different memory locations. Data races only apply to accesses to the *same* memory location.